# Camel Multicast Route call order

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

**Task:**

- I want to create a batch job like route execution, due to my use case I have to use custom batch processing.
- Implemented batch processing as a synchronous route from route `multicast(a,save)` -> `multicast(b, save)` -> `multicast(c, save)` -> `multicast(d, save)`. On each route, I'm using a `multicast` to save the current status where the process is currently. So later if something goes wrong, I have clear logs about the batch process.
- The mentioned save route is an ActiveMQ route with a single consumer and a single producer
- The mentioned `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` route is a `direct:` call to the route
- The mentioned ActiveMQ is a FIFO queue

**Issue:**

- When Route `a` called then it starts to executes the routes as described, so first `a` -> `b` -> `c` -> `d`. HOWEVER, the save route call from the `multicast` seems to go from Last to first. So, Save route called in this order: `d` -> `c` -> `b` -> `a`
- I tried to use `.parallelProcessing()` which seem to start a new process to other routes in the `multicast`, but then what happens is it completely forgets the route and saving not happening to the save route.

**Desired Behavior:**

- Synchronous execution of `a` -> `b` -> `c` -> `d`
- Synchronous execution of save route in order of `a` -> `b` -> `c` -> `d`

**Relevant Example Code:**

```java
private static final String a = "direct:a";
private static final String b = "direct:b";
private static final String c = "direct:c";
private static final String d = "direct:d";

private static final String save = "activemq:save";

private static final String toFile = "file:///camel-logs/batch-status";

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    ExceptionHandlerBuilder.retry(this);

    from(a)
        .multicast().parallelProcessing()
        .to(b, save);

    from(b)
        .multicast().parallelProcessing()
        .to(c, save);

    from(c)
        .multicast().parallelProcessing()
        .to(d, save);

    from(d)
        .multicast().parallelProcessing()
        .to("mock:end", save);
                
    from(save)
        .process(new ModifyText())
        .to(toFile + "?fileExist=Append&charset=utf-8");
}
```

EDIT:

- It see there is a possibility that there might be some issue with the configuration of the activeMQ so just in case i added the configuration codes of the JMS component

Component:

```
public class Components { 
@Bean 
public JmsComponent jmsComponent() throws JmsException { 
ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQCF = Utilities.getActiveMQFactory(); 
JmsComponent jms = new JmsComponent(); 
jms.setConnectionFactory(activeMQCF); 
return jms; 
} 
}
```

Function:

```
    public static ActiveMQConnectionFactory getActiveMQFactory() {
        logger.debug("getActiveMQFactory called");
        String brokerUrl = getActiveMQConfig();

        ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQCF = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        activeMQCF.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
        activeMQCF.setUserName(activeMQUserName);
        activeMQCF.setPassword(activeMQPassword);
        return activeMQCF;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "it completely forgets the route and saving not happening"? Do you receive messages on the queue or not? And if yes, in what order?

Comment: its just nothing happens, no message to queue nothing. like the multicast part of the route is forgotten. Not entirely sure why...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the behavior without `parallelProcessing` is because of the **synchronous request-reply nature of `direct` routes**.

Your chaining of the direct routes a, b, c and d is like the chaining of four normal methods. The **call chain** goes a, b, c, d, but the **"return values" go backwards**: d, c, b, a.

Similar, when route a calls b it **holds open the request because it expects a reply**. Therefore route d is the first to finish. And the finish of the route is the moment that triggers "save" in the multicast.

Unfortunately I have **no idea why the `parallelProcessing` messes things up** like this. When I read the [Camel Multicast docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.12.x/eips/multicast-eip.html), I agree that `parallelProcessing` should help because the message is sent to both routes in parallel.

Since your primary workflow is just a, b, c, d and the "save" is more like a state backup you could try to remove the multicast and use the [WireTap EIP](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.12.x/eips/wireTap-eip.html) to send messages to your save route.

```
from("direct:a")
    .to("direct:b")
    .wireTap("activemq:save")
    .to("direct:c")
    ...
```

Comment: Hello, i did try wireTap but for whatever reason the logs were not saved even tho messages reached activeMQ.

Currently i tried to do it in a way where i started to use ProducerTemplates before each .To() but still experiencing weird issues. At this point i think it might be something with ActiveMQ and ApacheCamel how they work together... will write another question about that. But long story short, no solution yet from my end.

Comment: Well, if the messages arrive at the queue but the logs are not saved, there must be an issue in the save route itself. For the main problem: Have you tried to replace the ActiveMQ endpoint with a simple SEDA endpoint (async in-memory)? If it works like this my guess for the AMQ problem would be a transaction config issue

Comment: The message arrives to the queue, the message gets read from the queue also, but for whatever reason, in the application the logs not showing up when the read has happened, plus it writes to a file which is equal to the client ID of the ActiveMQ, Either way i will add the config im using for the jms & activeMQ component in a moment

Comment: tried with direct, and with seda , both behaves the same way

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the question:

- The answer to my question is still most welcome, however now I found a work around

Solution:

- Between every from().to() now I added a .processor() in that processor I was able to add a producer template which can call the endpoint correctly
- Removed ActiveMQ

Route:

```
private static final String Save = "direct:save"
```

Processor:

```
        public class SaveProcessor implements Processor {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                ProducerTemplate template = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
                template.send(Save, exchange);
        /** NOTE
         *  DO NOT USE any other functions which are not working with EXCHANGES.
         *  Functions that uses body, header values and such are bugged
         */ 
            }
        }
```

Implementation to route:

```
from(a)
    .process(new SaveProcessor())
    .to(b);
```

Comment: I was wrong this did not solve the whole issue... If i use multiple producerTemplates then things gets messy again