# Camel ProducerTemplate and ActiveMQ message and persistence issues

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

Issue:

- I have multiple route sending messages to an ActiveMQ queue which later gets processed by a processor to save status information
- The same message sending from ProducerTemplate to ActiveMQ queue somehow breakes the same code by not triggering logs on console, and saving status information to a randomly generated file name.

Desired Behavior:

- Both sending method gets the messages processed the same way

Code Explanation:

- On below codes the Save processor is the one producing the weird behavior where logs dont show up on console and writes to some random file, file name is basically the clientID from ActiveMQ
- StartRoute calling the activemq:save works correctly

Code:

```
public class Save implements Processor {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        try {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>() {};
            map.put(".....", ".....");
            map.put(".....", ".....");
            map.put(".....", ".....");
            map.put(".....", ".....");

            ProducerTemplate template = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
            String response = template.requestBodyAndHeaders("activemq:save", "Batch Job Started", map, String.class);
            
            FluentProducerTemplate FluentTemplate = exchange.getContext().createFluentProducerTemplate();
            String result = FluentTemplate
                    .withHeader(".....", ".....")
                    .withHeader(".....", ".....")
                    .withHeader(".....", ".....")
                    .withHeader(".....", ".....")
                    .withHeader(".....", ".....")
                    .to("activemq:save")
                    .request(String.class);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            .....
            }
    }
}

public class StartRoute extends RouteBuilder {
            restConfiguration()
                .component("servlet")
                .enableCORS(true);
                
        rest("/start").id("start")
                .post("/{filename}")
                .route()
                .....
                .process(new Save())
                .wireTap(startBackgroundProcessRoute)
                .to("activemq:save")
                .endRest();
}

public class SaveRoute extends RouteBuilder {
        from("activemq:save")
                .log("started saving")
                .process(new FormatText())
                .to("file:///status");
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `requestBodyAndHeaders` and not `sendBodyAndHeaders`? That means you want to do request/reply messaging over JMS. Not sure if this needs specific message headers to work (`replyTo` and `correlationId`)

Comment: Good point, changed to sendBodyAndHeaders, tho its still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This question came from my original problem described here:

- [Camel Multicast Route call order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69540959/camel-multicast-route-call-order/69628917#69628917)

Solution can be found also there:

- [Camel Multicast Route call order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69540959/camel-multicast-route-call-order/69628917#69628917)

However to satisfy this question:

- It seems Camel have few bugs regarding producer templates and maybe ActiveMQ, this is my initial conclusion.

The Only way i was able to use ProducerTemplate without issue is to use the send function with Exchanges, send() sends the messages correctly to the ActiveMQ same way as the to() however for whatever reason the content was still not written to the file.
After I dropped the ActiveMQ between the routes, everything started to work consistently. So possible miss configuration on ActiveMQ component or possible another camel framework bug.

If anyone knows the exact answer i would be happy to hear / see the reason for this behavior.

Code example:

```
        public class SaveProcessor implements Processor {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                ProducerTemplate template = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();
                template.send(Utilities.trackBatchJobStatus, exchange);
        /** NOTE
         *  DO NOT USE any other functions which are not working with EXCHANGES.
         *  Functions that uses body, header values and such are bugged
         */ 
            }
        }
```

Comment: I was wrong this did not solve the whole issue... If i use multiple producerTemplates then things gets messy again